# What does ! mean in sequences?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, notation, factorial

I'm doing a sequences problem where I have to write the first five terms of a sequence. It looks normal, but there is an exclamation mark on the denominator:

$$a_n = \frac{1}{(n + 1)!}$$

&

$$a_n = \frac{(-1)^{n}n}{n! + 1}$$

What does the exclamation mark mean, and how do I go about this differently with the exclamation mark?

Comment: $n!$ is the [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) of $n$. (See the link.)

Comment: That’s the [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) sign: $n!=n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots\cdot2\cdot1$, and we define $0!=1$. Thus, $4!=4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1=24$.

Comment: It means that sequences are very exciting!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The factorial of a number is represented by the exclamation point (!).
The factorial of a number $x$ is often described as the product of all positive integers less then or equal to $x$.  For example:

$$4! = 4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1 = 24$$

It is often also useful to describe $x!$ in a recursive relation:

$$x! = x(x-1)!$$

where $0! = 1$.

This method is often good because it helps explain why $0!=1$ (see also the "empty product" for more on this).  Using the above explanation, we may find $4!$:

$$4! = 4(3)! = 4(3)(2)!  = \cdots = 4(3)(2)(1)(0)! = 4(3)(2)(1)(1) = 24$$

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: For the record: $0!=1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

If the number is 4! then you count down so it would be $4\times 3 \times 2\times 1= 24$. Another thing is that if the number is 7! you would count down until you get to two. So it would be $7\times 6\times 5\times 3\times 2 =5040$ 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 I just put in the 4 that was not listed although the answer is still 5040.

Comment: It might be confusing to someone who has never seen factorials before if you count down to 1 in one example and 2 in another example (even though the result is the same).

Comment: @Hockeylover It's actually defined recursively and one "counts down" to $0! :=1$.